# warning: There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am getting this error when I run my project

```
WARNING in ./src/components/Header/index.scss
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
```

However I have no module called Header. I have a module called header (lower case) but I'm not sure why it still think the Header module exists? I have trie deleting my bundle to no avail.
What else can I do to try all references to this module that doesn't exist?

Comment: `Header` and `header` are the same **when case is ignored**.

Comment: @Barmar yes but im saying there is no module Header so why does it think there is ?

Comment: Where does it say that a module named `Header` exists?

Comment: after i run webpack run watch

Answer (score 3):

Are you using React.js? I had this same problem and the solution was to change

```
var React = require('React');
```

into

```
var React = require('react');
```

I'm not sure how this explains the error message, if you search around you can see people get this error message for another reason on Window. Something about how Node.js does file paths